# How does $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} = \frac{(n+1) - n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How does $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} = \frac{(n+1) - n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$  ?

What are the exact steps to get to the right side from the left?

Comment: You can't because they are not equal. Check your signs. It should be $+$ somewhere, perhaps in the denominator.

Comment: There should be a $+$ in the denominator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the hint with almost solution and quite good technic for such problems.

$$ \bigg( \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} \bigg) \cdot 1 = \bigg( \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} \bigg) \cdot \frac{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}$$

Useful formula for this task:

$$ \bigg( \sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b} \bigg) \cdot \bigg( \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} \bigg) = a - b $$

Answer (score 4):

**hint**: $ 1 = (n+1) - n = \left(\sqrt{n+1}\right)^2 - \left(\sqrt{n}\right)^2 = \left(\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}\right)(?-?)$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Evaluate $$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} = (\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$$